# Overriding @Path at Jersey

Tags: java, path, jersey

I've been trying to make a Jersey app that takes the following structure from the path:

Example 1 (http:// omitted due to stackoverflow restrictions)
example.com/source/{source-id}/
example.com/source/

With code (error handling and unneeded code omitted):

With code (sum up):

```
@Path("/source/")
public class SourceREST {
...
 @GET
 public Response getSource() {
  return Response.ok("Sources List (no field)").build();
 }

 @GET
 @Path("/{source-id}")
 public Response getSource(@PathParam("source-id") String sourceID) {
  return Response.ok("Source: " + sourceID).build();
 }

}
```

It works fine.

Example 2:
example.com/data/{source-id}/{info-id}/
example.com/data/{source-id}/

With code (error handling and unneeded code omitted):

```
@Path("/data/")
public class DataREST {
...

 @GET
 @Path("/{source-id}")
 public Response getContext(@PathParam("source-id") String sourceID) {
  return Response.ok("Source: " + sourceID + " Last ContextInfo").build();
 }

 @GET
 @Path("/{source-id}/{data-id}")
 public Response getContext(@PathParam("source-id") String sourceID, 
   @PathParam("data-id") String dataID) {
  return Response.ok("Source: " + sourceID + " Data: " + dataID).build();

 }
}
```

In example 2, I can access an URL like example.com/data/111/222/ fine, but trying to get hexample.com/data/111/ gives me a 405 Error Code (Method Not Allowed). I've tried also to make a whole method that checks if {data-id} is empty or blank and in that case process the petition as in the first method, but doesn't work either.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried example.com/data/111 (without leading slash)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just pasted your example 2 into a Resource and it seems to work fine.  I am using Jersey 1.1.5.

Below are the results from my tests.

http://localhost:8090/MyHealth/helloworld/111

```
Source: 111 Last ContextInfo
```

http://localhost:8090/MyHealth/helloworld/111/

```
Source: 111 Last ContextInfo
```

http://localhost:8090/MyHealth/helloworld/111/222

```
Source: 111 Data: 222
```

http://localhost:8090/MyHealth/helloworld/111/222/

```
Source: 111 Data: 222
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using path for root resource like `@Path("/data/{source-id}")`. Then the first method would only have `@GET` annotation while the second one would have `@GET @Path("{data-id}")`.

What is more, I would suggest using different method names (while they probably performs different actions), but I'm not sure that it is the cause of your problem.