# Jersey embedded @Path

Tags: java, rest, path, jersey

I am trying to embed path's in a class like so:

```
@Service("adminSvc")
@Path("/admin")
public class AdminSvc {
    @GET
    public String getStuff(){
        return "stuff";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("/stuff")
    public String moreStuff(){
        return "even more stuff";
    }

}
```

the goal is to have a page return for admin, then return a page for /admin/stuff
this unfortunately is returning a 405 when i attempt it, but according to:
[Overriding @Path at Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681504/overriding-path-at-jersey)

it should be working fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: And now it works.  I think it was environmental... If i figure out how to reproduce it will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've copied and pasted that code (excluding the @Service) into one of my Jersey (1.7) projects and it works as intended.

/admin returns "stuff"

/admin/stuff returns "even more stuff"

Comment: the @Service is an artifact of spring, i have a hard time believing it would be causing it.  Its good to know that the code works though!

Answer (score 0):

If yout get a `405 Method Not Allowed` this means you use an `Accept` header that doesn't match `MediaType.TEXT_HTML` which probably is only a shortcut for `text/html`. So check your HTTP request.

What is the value of `@Produces(...)` for your whole Resource?

Comment: This is true for `406 Not Acceptable` responses, but in case of `405` it's related to request method (GET, POST, PUT...), not acceptable content types.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean.  Added @Produces... to the entire class with no effect.  Ill capture the http response and see if i can figure it out from there.  Thanks